# Test If String Contains All Characters That Make Up Another String

Tags: javascript, regex, string, algorithm

I am trying to use Javascript to see if a certain string contains all characters that make up another string.

For instance, the word "hello" contains all characters that make up the word "hell." Also, the word "hellowy" contains all characters that make up the word "yellow."

Most importantly, the method needs to work irrespective of the order of characters in both string. In addition, the numbers of characters matters. "Hel" does not contain all characters to make up "hell." This refers strictly to the number of characters: one needs two l's to make word "hell" and "hel" only has one.

Further clarifying the question, I am not worried if I am left with some "unused" characters after the composition of the substring from the characters of the string. That is, "helll" still should contain all letters for the word "hell."

How can I accomplish this efficiently? Perhaps there is a regex solution? Speed is somewhat of an issue, but not absolutely critical.

Comment: _""Hel" does not contain all characters to make up "hell.""_? `"hel"` does contain all characters which comprise `"hell"` . Do you mean by case-sensitivity?

Comment: No. Only by the quantity of characters. You need two l's to make word "hell" and "hel" only has one.

Comment: Note,  that is an important requirement which did not appear to be included at original Question? You should be able to check input string `.length` is equal to matching string `.length`

Comment: I shall add that now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
function test(string, substring) {
    var letters = [...string];
    return [...substring].every(x => {
        var index = letters.indexOf(x);
        if (~index) {
            letters.splice(index, 1);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

`Every` will fail in the first falsy value, then it does not search *every* letter.

Comment: What does this notation do? `[...string]`

Comment: Also, is the `Set` a built in JS feature?

Comment: Got it. Will this still work if no repetitions are allowed? That is, if `string = "hel"` and `substring = "hell"` the function should return false. In other words, the number of characters matters.

Comment: @MadPhysicist. Edited

Comment: This looks really clever. I shall understand and test it. :)

Comment: Also, why do you have two arguments in `.forEach(mySet.add, mySet);` in your original code? Why the second argument? The first seems somewhat intuitive and common.

Comment: `mySet.add` is just a function, `, mySet` (second argument) binds the function to the `Set` itself

Comment: @MadPhysicist. It could be, for example: `((new Set).add, mySet)`

Comment: In other words, it lets the callback know which set actually gets the new item? Seems weird as there is already mySet.add in the name of the callback. It seems like a redundancy to me, but I am sure I am missing something ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118104/discussion-between-madphysicist-and-guedes).

Comment: Does Answer check for equal string `.length` of `string`, `substring`?

Comment: I don't think it is needed, can you show one example?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Why was original Question updated to include requirement _"In addition, the numbers of characters matters. "Hel" does not contain all characters to make up "hell." This refers strictly to the number of characters: one needs two l's to make word "hell" and "hel" only has one."_ if not applicable? That is, `test("hell", "hel")` returns `true`, where expected result would be `false`?

Comment: @guest271314 I am not sure what you are confused about. I updated the question after you pointed out to me your confusion about the number of characters versus casing of letters. Since the number of characters is important in my case, I updated the question.

Comment: @MadPhysicist _"Since the number of characters is important in my case, I updated the question."_ Yes, accepted Answer does not check for same `.length` of input and matching strings; have you tried `test("hell", "hel")`? Expected result should be `false`, correct?

Comment: "Does Answer check for equal string .length of string, substring?" Yes, it seems to work for "hello" and "ehllo"

Comment: @MadPhysicist Have you tried the example that you included at updated Question? `test("hell", "hel")`?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, for that case it is false both in my original intention and the Guede's function's output.

Comment: @MadPhysicist _"Yes, for that case it is false both in my original intention and the Guede's function's output."_ ? `test("helll", "hell")` and `test("hell", "hel")` return `true`, `test("hel", "hell")` returns `false`

Comment: Alright, on string = 'hell' and 'hel' I get true which is expected because there are enough letters. In this case, I am not worried about using up all letters in the string so long as I can compose the substring while keeping the quantity of characters in check when it comes to doubled letters.

Comment: 'Yes, for that case it is false both in my original intention and the Guede's function's output.' I meant to say TRUE here.

Comment: @MadPhysicist _"Alright, on string = 'hell' and 'hel' I get true which is expected because there are enough letters. In this case, I am not worried about using up all letters in the string so long as I can compose the substring"_ ? That description does not appear at original Question, or updated Question _"This refers strictly to the number of characters: one needs two l's to make word "hell" and "hel" only has one."_ ? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @guest271314 Perhaps. I edited to clarify the question further.

Comment: @MadPhysicist You already Accepted the present Answer. The original Question and subsequent update were unclear as to requirement relevant to comparing `.length` of input and matching strings. How does updating Question at this point help users who answered initial Question? Note, the link at previous comment may help at possible future Question

Comment: @guest271314 There is nothing you or I can do about it at this point. Also, that is why I up-vote everyone who attempts to answer my questions.

Answer (score 1):

Edit, Updated

> In addition, the numbers of characters matters. "Hel" does not contain
>   all characters to make up "hell."

You can use a variable to store `Boolean` value, `for..of` loop, `String.prototype.indexOf()` check for, set `Boolean` variable, `break` loop if `false`.

You should also be able include check if input string `.length` is equal to matching string `.length` at `if` condition, set variable to `false` if the two string `.length` properties are not equal.

```
var str = "hell";
var match = "hel";
var bool = true; 
for (var prop of str) {
  if (str.length !== match.length || match.indexOf(prop) === -1) {
    bool = false; break;
  }
};
console.log(bool); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

If the number of letters matters then maybe something like this:

```
function test(string, substring) {
    var regexp = new RegExp(substring.split("").sort().map(function(s) { return s + "+"; }).join(""));
    return regexp.test(string.split("").sort().join(""));
}
```

This is slower than the above answers, but if there is some repetition in the strings then it's possible to cache and get better speed performance than the other answers:

```
var cache1 = { };
var cache2 = { };
function test2(string, substring) {
    var regexp = cache1[substring];
    if (!regexp) {
        regexp = new RegExp(substring.split("").sort().map(function(s) { return s + "+"; }).join(""));
        cache1[substring] = regexp;
    }

    var string2 = cache2[string];
    if (!string2) {
        string2 = string.split("").sort().join("");
        cache2[string] = string2;
    }

    return regexp.test(string2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make some training I came up with this thing:

```
function test(str, substring) {
  var arr_str = str.toLowerCase().split('');
  var arr_substr = substring.toLowerCase().split('');

  return arr_substr.filter(function(each) {
    return arr_str.indexOf(each) === -1;
  }).length === 0;
}

console.log(test("Alien", "line")); // true
console.log(test("Hello", "hello")); // true
console.log(test("hello", "hey")); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried something leaning on the comments from others and came up with this. It basically uses a **count** variable each time a letter in the substring returns a positive index value, then checks whether the total count is equal to the length of the substring(*the logic being that any letter that returns -1 doesn't exist and would not be counted*). If the count is equal, then all the letters have passed the test, if not, it fails the test.

It works for reversed letters, repeated letters in a substring(i.e 'heell' as a substring would also pass the test with 'hello'.

```
function test(str, substring) {
    let str1 = str.toLowerCase();
    let str2 = substring.toLowerCase();
    let count = 0;
    let answer = false;

    for(let i of str2){
        if(str1.indexOf(i) >= 0) {
            count+=1;
        }
    }
    return str2.length == count ? answer = true : answer;
}

console.log(test("Alien", "line")); // true
console.log(test("Hello", "olleh")); // true
console.log(test("hello", "hey")); // false
```